# Expressing Maxwell's equations in tensor form using Electromagnetic field strength tensor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, tensor-calculus

I have yet another derivation question from Carroll's General Relativity textbook. Given the electromagnetic field strength tensor is of the form: $$ F_{\mu\upsilon} = 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
0 & -E_1 & -E_2 & -E_3\\
E_1 & 0 & B_3 & -B_2\\
E_2 & -B_3 & 0 & B_1\\
E_3 & B_2 & -B_1 & 0\\
\end{matrix}
\right) 
= -F_{\upsilon\mu}$$

The Maxwell's equations are expressed in component notation:
$$
\bar{\epsilon}^{ijk}\partial_jB_k - \partial_0E^i = J^i\\
\partial_iE^i = J^0\\
\bar{\epsilon}^{ijk}\partial_jE_k + \partial_0B^i = 0\\
\partial_iB^i = 0.$$

Given that the field strength tensor can be written in the two tensor equations $F^{0i} = E^i$ and $F^{ij} = \bar{\epsilon}^{ijk}B_k$, how do I reduce the last two equations to the form, $$ \partial_{\lambda} F_{\mu \nu} + \partial_{\mu} F_{\nu \lambda}+ \partial_{\nu} F_{\lambda \mu} = 0,\qquad \mu,\nu,\lambda=0,1,2,3 $$

Comment: "Maxwell's equations are expressed in tensor notation" Your expressions are not tensor notation. For example, for $E^i$ you should write $F^{0i}$.

Comment: @mycts: No, he has *defined* $E^i := F^{0i}$. This is perfectly valid in the indexful tensor notation.

Comment: @MoziburUllah $E^i$is a tensor component but this character is not expressed in the notation.

Comment: @mycts: Yes, it is. Moreover, $E^i$ actually expresses the full tensor in what is known as the Abstract Index Notation.

Comment: @MoziburUllah There should be 2 indices.

Comment: @my2cts: One index of two has been fixed to zero and hence there is only one free index remaining. This is basic stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $F_{ij} = \epsilon_{ijk}B^k$ one has $\epsilon^{lij} F_{ij} = \epsilon^{lij}\epsilon_{ijk}B^k = 2\delta_{lk} B^k$, hence $B^l = \frac{1}{2} \epsilon^{lij} F_{ij}$.

The third Maxwell's equation in OP's question can be expressed with the field strength tensor $F_{\mu\nu}$ according to

\begin{align}
0 &=  \epsilon^{ijk} \partial_j E_k + \partial_0 B^i \\
&= -\epsilon^{ijk} \partial_j F_{k0} + \frac{1}{2} \epsilon^{ikl} \partial_0 F_{kl}\\
&= -2\epsilon^{ijk} \partial_j F_{k0} + \epsilon^{ijk} \partial_0 F_{jk}\\
&=-\epsilon^{ijk} \partial_0 F_{jk} + \epsilon^{ijk} \partial_j F_{k0} - \epsilon^{ijk} \partial_j F_{0k}\ .
\end{align}

The Bianchi identity, i.e., the relation $\partial_\mu F_{\alpha\beta}+ \partial_\alpha F_{\beta\mu}+ \partial_\beta F_{\mu\alpha} =0$, can be compactly arrange with a four-dimensional totally antisymmetric [Levi-Civita symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol) $$\epsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta} \partial_\beta F_{\gamma\delta}=0$$
with the property $\epsilon^{0\beta\gamma\delta}=\epsilon^{ijk}$.

Replacing the three-dimensional Levi-Civita symbol we obtain
\begin{align}
0&=-\epsilon^{ijk} \partial_0 F_{jk} + \epsilon^{ijk} \partial_j F_{k0} - \epsilon^{ijk} \partial_j F_{0k}\\
&=\epsilon^{i0jk} \partial_0 F_{jk} + \epsilon^{ij0k} \partial_j F_{k0} + \epsilon^{ijk0} \partial_j F_{0k}\\
&=\epsilon^{i\beta\gamma\delta} \partial_\beta F_{\gamma\delta}\ .
\end{align}

The still missing case $\alpha=0$ follows immediately from the last Maxwell's equation:
\begin{align}
0&=\partial_i B^i\\
&=\epsilon^{ijk} \partial_i F_{jk}\\
&=\epsilon^{0\beta\gamma\delta}\partial_\beta F_{\gamma\delta}\ ,
\end{align}
which eventually reduces to the Bianchi identity.

PS: note the sign for covariant and contravariant indices, e.g. $F_{0i}=\eta_{00}\eta_{ij}F^{0j}=-F^{0i}$.

Comment: Where does the factor of 2 come from, when you contract the two Levi-Civita tensors in obtaining $B^l$?

Comment: @Chidi: contracting over two indices of a product of two Levi-Civita symbols (it is not a tensor) yields $\epsilon^{ijk}\epsilon_{ljk} = 3 \delta_{il} - \delta_{ij} \delta_{jl} = 2 \delta_{il}$. 

Remark: 
In general, one can rewrite the Levi-Civita symbol as a determinant and can obtain in this way quite easily all desired contractions, see for example [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/278288/product-of-levi-civita-symbols).

Comment: Did not know the product of two Levi-Civita symbols could be calculated in that manner. Thank you

Comment: @Chidi: your welcome and great that I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I've been [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/687479/correct-equation-for-the-contravariant-electric-displacement-tensor-underline) before(I got help from a professor offsite)! The matrix multiplication representation of electromagnetism in general relativity is
$$\begin{matrix}\vec{f}=\widetilde{F}\overleftarrow{J}&\widetilde{F}=\nabla\vec{A}-\left(\nabla\vec{A}\right)^T\\\overleftarrow{J}=\frac{1}{\mu_0}\nabla\cdot\underline{F}=\nabla\cdot\underline{\mathcal{D}}&\underline{\mathcal{D}}=\frac{1}{\mu_0}\underline{F}\\\end{matrix}$$
where
$$\begin{matrix}\underline{M}={\widetilde{g}}^{-1}\widetilde{M}{\widetilde{g}}^{-1}&\left(\nabla\widetilde{M}\right)_{ijk}=\left(\frac{\partial M_{jk}}{\partial x_i}\right)&\left(\widetilde{M}\right)_i=\left[\begin{matrix}M_{i1}\\M_{i2}\\M_{i3}\\M_{i4}\\\end{matrix}\right]\\\widetilde{M}=\widetilde{g}\underline{M}\widetilde{g}&\nabla\cdot\widetilde{M}=\sum_{i}\left(\frac{\partial\left(\widetilde{M}\right)_i}{\partial x_i}\right)&\nabla\cdot\left(f\widetilde{M}\right)=f\left(\nabla\cdot\widetilde{M}\right)+{\widetilde{M}}^T\nabla f\\\end{matrix}$$
A covariant matrix is represented by $\widetilde{M}$, a contravariant matrix is represented by $\underline{M}$, a covariant vector is represented by $\vec{A}$, and a contravariant vector is represented by $\overleftarrow{J}$.

Due to how the Faraday tensor is defined with the magnetic vector potential, we can prove
$$\left(\frac{\partial F_{\mu\nu}}{\partial x_\lambda}\right)+\left(\frac{\partial F_{\nu\lambda}}{\partial x_\mu}\right)+\left(\frac{\partial F_{\lambda\mu}}{\partial x_\nu}\right)=\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_\lambda}\left(\left(\frac{\partial A_\nu}{\partial x_\mu}\right)-\left(\frac{\partial A_\mu}{\partial x_\nu}\right)\right)\right)+\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_\mu}\left(\left(\frac{\partial A_\lambda}{\partial x_\nu}\right)-\left(\frac{\partial A_\nu}{\partial x_\lambda}\right)\right)\right)+\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_\nu}\left(\left(\frac{\partial A_\mu}{\partial x_\lambda}\right)-\left(\frac{\partial A_\lambda}{\partial x_\mu}\right)\right)\right)=\left(\left(\frac{\partial^2A_\nu}{\partial x_\mu\partial x_\lambda}\right)-\left(\frac{\partial^2A_\nu}{\partial x_\mu\partial x_\lambda}\right)\right)+\left(\left(\frac{\partial^2A_\mu}{\partial x_\nu\partial x_\lambda}\right)-\left(\frac{\partial^2A_\mu}{\partial x_\nu\partial x_\lambda}\right)\right)+\left(\left(\frac{\partial^2A_\lambda}{\partial x_\mu\partial x_\nu}\right)-\left(\frac{\partial^2A_\lambda}{\partial x_\mu\partial x_\nu}\right)\right)=0$$

\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial F_{\mu\nu}}{\partial x_\lambda}+\frac{\partial F_{\nu\lambda}}{\partial x_\mu}+\frac{\partial F_{\lambda\mu}}{\partial x_\nu}=
\nonumber\\
&\frac{\partial}{\partial x_\lambda}\left(\frac{\partial A_\nu}{\partial x_\mu}-\frac{\partial A_\mu}{\partial x_\nu}\right)+\frac{\partial}{\partial x_\mu}\left(\frac{\partial A_\lambda}{\partial x_\nu}-\frac{\partial A_\nu}{\partial x_\lambda}\right)+\frac{\partial}{\partial x_\nu}\left(\frac{\partial A_\mu}{\partial x_\lambda}-\frac{\partial A_\lambda}{\partial x_\mu}\right)=
\tag{01}\label{01}\\
&\left(\frac{\partial^2A_\nu}{\partial x_\mu\partial x_\lambda}-\frac{\partial^2A_\nu}{\partial x_\mu\partial x_\lambda}\right)+\left(\frac{\partial^2A_\mu}{\partial x_\nu\partial x_\lambda}-\frac{\partial^2A_\mu}{\partial x_\nu\partial x_\lambda}\right)+\left(\frac{\partial^2A_\lambda}{\partial x_\mu\partial x_\nu}-\frac{\partial^2A_\lambda}{\partial x_\mu\partial x_\nu}\right)=0
\nonumber
\end{align}

Comment: I edit your last equation deleting unnecessary parentheses keeping your old one.  If you don't like this edit cancel it.